# VGA levels, why are they wrong?

Tags: measurement, voltage-measurement, vga

I read everywhere on the Internet that voltage levels in the color components of a VGA cable should go from 0 V (dark channel) to 0.7 V (maximum brightness for that channel). However I tried to measure the voltage coming out of two video cards that I own and I obtained levels between 1.4 and 1.6 V. At the same time I measure the expected output impedance (75 Ohm), because the voltage drops of the right factor when putting a resistor in parallel.

What might be the cause of this discrepancy? Is there any easy error that I might be doing or should I expect that a VGA card may emit higher voltages than the standard 0.7 V?

I am rather sure that the oscilloscope is correctly calibrated because it agrees with at least two testers I have.

Comment: Is the 1.4V to 1.6V level measured before terminating the line? Can you clear this up?

Comment: @Andyaka Oh yes, you're right, I did not consider that I have to terminate the line with a 75 Ohm resistance to measure the actual voltage. Sorry for the dumb question, I am still in my beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @Andyaka Oh yes, you're right, I did not consider that I have to
>   terminate the line with a 75 Ohm resistance to measure the actual
>   voltage.

Try terminating the line!

Comment: It works, I can correctly measure 0.7 V. Thanks again.